# error unzip: End-of-central-directory signature not found

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, unzip

> `!unzip '/content/Flowers-Dataset (1).zip'`

I tried unzipping using python command !unzip in google colab. I tried re-downloading the zip file and uploading but the error is still same as below,

```
Archive:  /content/Flowers-Dataset (1).zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /content/Flowers-Dataset (1).zip or
        /content/Flowers-Dataset (1).zip.zip, and cannot find /content/Flowers-Dataset (1).zip.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: The message is extremely detailed, are you sure you have all the files from that archive? Check it's hash signature if the provider of the file has it, also.

Comment: Maybe original file is broken and downloading can't help. OR maybe it is splitted in many files and it needs `/content/Flowers-Dataset (2).zip`, `/content/Flowers-Dataset (3).zip`, etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow is limited to questions about software development. If this would happen to someone using `unzip` on the command line without Python or Collaboratory, what makes it a SO question? Either way, we need a [mre], and in this case that means the ability to download and inspect a file for which the same problem occurs (such that an explanation satisfactory for the OP for that file would be satisfactory for their real dataset as well).

Comment: BTW, if this _isn't_ the obvious thing it looks like (and that the error message says it probably is), you could get a more useful exception by using the Python `zipfile` module. But TBH, I'd be very surprised if it _wasn't_ the obvious thing.

Answer (score 4):

Is `/content/Flowers-Dataset (1).zip` available publicly? If so, can you post a link? That will make it much easier to fault find the issue.

Also, how did you do the download?

The message `End-of-central-directory signature not found` means one of the following:

### The file isn't a zip file at all.

If you have access to a linux/Mac (or access to WSL on Windows), run `file /content/Flowers-Dataset (1).zip'`. If it is a zip file, you should get something like this

```
$ file test.zip 
test.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract, compression method=store
```

If the `file` command doesn't say it is a zip file, can you post the output?

### The file is a zip file, but the contents have become corrupted or truncated.

Try running `unzip -FF '/content/Flowers-Dataset (1).zip'`. That will attempt to extract the files that are recoverable. If that does recover files, the question then is why the zip file has been corrupted. To understand that we need to either get access to the zip file or know more about how you downloaded it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your file is uploaded successfully before running the command.

You can use this command to unzip the file on collab:

```
unzip dataset_location -d dataset_extract_location
```